# Solr Luke requires numTerms in order to return docs count

Tags: solr, lucene, luke

Using Luke in Solr, I'd like to return the total amount of docs per field, but it only returns the docs total when I have a ?numTerms set to at least 1. This slows down the Luke request significantly especially when using the values to populate an autocomplete dropdown. About 1 sec vs 5 secs per request. Is there an alternative, faster way to get the docs count?

Answer (score 0):

I know that Luke displays the # of docs containing each field at startup -- why not look at the Luke sources? It is Open Source, after all...

Once you have all of the field doc counts, just cache them away so you don't have to get them again.